# Couldn't start vnc in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I installed tight server in raspbian, after that when i executed command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tightvncserver start
```

its showing error

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
A VNC server is already running as :1
Starting vncserver for pi
```

the second last line says, its already running as :1.

I tried to connect with vnc but my pc says

[image: Error message in osx]

While trying to set LC_ALL using ,

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I face following error

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I think the problem here has nothing to do with locale, it has to do with trying to use Apple Screen Sharing. Apparently it is possible, but it is complicated. The recommendation from RPi is to use realvnc. See instructions here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/mac.md

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed. I followed @goldilocks suggestions and I'm no longer getting the locale warnings, but I still have the vncserver problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the locale error may not solve the vncserver problem, but you should solve it first in any case.

First, make sure you have locale files installed properly.  There should be a `/usr/share/i18n/locales` directory with a long list of files in including `en_US`.  You don't have to use that as your locale, but I'm going to in this example.  If the directory doesn't exist or the file isn't there, run `apt-get install locales`.  If it is supposedly already installed, `apt-get --reinstall install locales`.

Next,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

You get a menu of which ones to do.  Choose, e.g., `en_US.UTF-8`.  You can choose more than one.  You'll also get to choose the default.

Log in again and things should be fixed.

---

*[This is from an earlier version of the answer that didn't use `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.]*

Once/if that directory [`/usr/share/i18n/locales`] is okay you need to look at `/etc/locale.gen`.  If it does not exist, create it containing one line:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

If it does exist, look for that line.  It's probably there with a `#` in front of it.  Remove that.  If it is not there, add the line.  Now run `locale-gen`.

Now the locales are hopefully straightened out, before you run vnc:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

And then try from the same command line.  If that then works, create a file in `/etc/profile.d` called `mine.sh` (or "anything-you-want".sh) with the line above in it.  This will then apply to all subsequent logins.  You could put it in `~/.profile`, but it should be global anyway.

Comment: It gives me an error saying , "-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
"

Comment: Okay, I've added a few paragraphs *at the beginning* above.

Comment: I'm still seeing the `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)` error message after following these instructions.

Comment: @ThomasW I've edited this to include `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, which just fixed the same problem after an upgrade to jessie and my previous more manual method did not work.

Comment: Do you recommend adding `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to someplace like the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @ThomasW If the locale is actually there it can't hurt.  Mine turned out not to be there because I had previously chosen just `en_CA.UTF.8`; that showed up when I ran `dpkg-reconfigure`.  I guess that is the meaning of the "Please check that....*are supported and installed*".

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late for answer :)

From the error (as you already mentioned) vncserver is already running as :1)

You should use the port(5901) with IP Address.

(if you are using vncviewer, issue the following command)

```
$vncviewer <ip_address>:5901
```

Even when you are using other tools try using `<ip_address>:port`